# Cannot install angular on elementary os!

Tags: system-installation, web-development

After `npm install -g @angular/cli` this is what I recive:

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@angular/cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ipaulbogdan/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#installation

> Install Globablly
>
> `npm install -g @angular/cli`
>
> Install Locally
>
> `npm install @angular/cli`

In Linux, every time you install something, when that something is Global means you need root access and when something is Local just with your user is enough

---

To translate that into commands

**Global**

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

**Local**

`npm install @angular/cli`

---

### ***Permission Denied***

You can see what is the problem clearly in the log

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
```

Probably the installer wants to write there but can's because only the `root` user can

Comment: Thanks man.Appreciate your help.It's working now.

Comment: Please use the answer below to fix the problem. It's not suggested to use `sudo` to install npm packages on linux. Follow the answer posted by `Ashraf Mirghani`

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Back up your computer.
On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```
 mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
 npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```
 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

On the command line, update your system variables:

```
source ~/.profile
```

To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

```
npm install -g jshint
```